# Condition statement to be used with "AfterCompileSolution" in tfsbuild

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

i need your help. I am running into a situation. I am trying to copy certain binaries into a particular folder. I am adding those task into "AfterCompileSolution" . I know it is incorrect, bcos it's gonna execute this step after every solution is compiled.

Here is my situation, i tried adding a condition like a SolutionFileName, but i get empty result. The target doesn't get executed because the SolutionFileName parameter is empty.

So do you know of any parameter that i can use between solutiontobuild i.e i want to copy certain binaries only after solution "A" is completed and i want these parameters to be part of "AfterCompileSolution" or maybe "BeforeCompileSolution"

Please suggest

Thanks
Satesh

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this but I believe you reference the file name with a syntax such as:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompileSolution" DependsOnTargets="RandomPreReqTarget">       
    <SomeTask Condition="'%(SolutionToBuildItem.Identity)' == 'ConditionValue'" />
</Target>
```

Another cool thing you can do is product extra properties in your SolutionToBuild item and reference them as metadata also like:

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(SolutionRoot)\$(SourceBranch)\RandomDirectory\Project.csproj">
  <Targets>Build</Targets>
  <Properties>OutDir=$(RandomDirectory);Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU</Properties>
  <GAC>True</GAC>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

You would then be able to access the metadata like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompileSolution" DependsOnTargets="RandomPreReqTarget">       
    <SomeTask Condition="'%(SolutionToBuildItem.GAC)' == 'True'" />
</Target>
```